# Can we get VID and PID from USB Flash drive in java?

Tags: java, usb-flash-drive

I have a requirement to get VID and PID of removable Flash Drive in java? I have googled a lot I can not get any proper answer. Many of the communities there are few instructions but there is no proper instructions, which packages I have to import. Among most of the answer are written in C++.

Thanks in advance.